# Trying to protect access to a specific .php file using this .htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to protect by IP address access to a particular .php file

I thought this would work but it doesn't.

The rule is meant to redirect the user to another URL, in this example to google.com

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?hidden\.php(.*)$ [OR]
    # To Allow
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^18\.132\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^124\.459\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://google.com/
    </IfModule>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You could do it in the PHP pretty easily. `if(!preg_match('/^(?:18\.132|124\.459)\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){` then a `header`.

Comment: What URL are you trying to protect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file you are trying to restrict is 'hidden.php', your rules might be more like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/hidden\.php
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(18\.132|124\.149)\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://google.com/
```

You are trying mix AND and OR conditions, so you either have to work your conditions to be all AND or OR statements, or you need to use two or more RewriteRules where the first skips or chains to the next set rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hidden\.php
# if not the hidden file(s), skip next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [skip=1]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^18\.132\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^124\.149\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
# if not one of the cond IP's redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://google.com/ [L,R]
```